# Is it possible to increase the PK somehow?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to increase the PK somehow?
I need to make it start at about 10000. Is there some sql statement I could execute directly in phpMyAdmin?

EDIT:
I need to be a bit more clear...

I need to update all rows with a PK over 2190 (about 2000 rows). Need to update them to start at about 10000 instead... So I do believe it is some sort of programming question...

Comment: PK meaning primary key? How is it currently generated? If it's a sequence just redefine the sequence to start at your desired value.

Comment: PK meaning primary key indeed. And PK is (int) AI. What I need is to like update all of the existing ones. Not just start new ones at a higher number...

Comment: This question is not programming-related, so it doesn't belong on stackoverflow. But we have a sister site dba.stackexchange.com which is especially for database administration questions like this.

Comment: Is the PK referenced by foreign keys in other tables? Or just a stand-along column you need to increase for some reaosn?

Comment: The PK is not linked to anything. I just need to update, and increase, the value of the records from 2190 and obove as a temporary fix. Data from two different tables have been inserted into a third one.

Comment: @ThomasK Updated my answer to reflect these changes. Word of advice - please make your question complete next time; you'll save time both of yours and fellow SOers trying to help you.

Comment: Voting to re-open. The "duplicate" is about new Primary Key values, this about modifying existing values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>Quoting [the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).</del>

So the question is about updating some set of values. Well, here's one way to do it:

```
UPDATE some_table 
   SET some_pk = 10000 + some_pk 
 WHERE some_pk > 2190
```

Still, you have to follow this with `ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000`; otherwise all the rows inserted after this UPDATE still get an old auto_increment. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, s VARCHAR(5), PRIMARY KEY (id));
INSERT INTO t (s) VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d'), ('e');

UPDATE t SET id = id + 10000 WHERE id > 3;
ALTER TABLE t AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;

INSERT INTO t (s) VALUES ('f');
```

Without `ALTER TABLE...` `'f'`'s id will be 6; with it - 10006.

Here's [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80780/1) illustrating this concept.

Answer (score 1):

If your table has already been created with an auto-incr. index, use

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```